# .htaccess redirecting all URLs except one

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess

I have a server running with the following directory structure:

```
/public_html
   | - /fingertools
   | - /css
   | - /static
   | - /media
   | - /js
   | - .htaccess
```

My .htaccess is in the root of the "public_html" folder, and the main files of the website are in the "fingertools" folder, which is a Django project.

I want to rewrite through the .htaccess all requests to http://mydomain.com/ to the "fingertools" folder, except any file inside http://mydomain.com/static/ should be redirected to the "static" folder.

I'm not able to do this, I need it to put all the CSS and JavaScript into this folder for the website to work.

I have this so far:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(fingertools)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ fingertools/$1 [L]
```

Which redirects me to my Django project, giving me a 404 error for not having the /static/ URL mapped in the urls.py file. Any ideas? Thank you very much

Comment: Don't do that. Django is not supposed to be placed under DocumentRoot folder. You should only map `/static/` folder *mapped* to requests, but the rest of the application/site should be exposed in some other way, e.g. as `wsgi` application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(fingertools|static)(/|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ fingertools/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Regexes are greed, so `fingertools|static` will match `fingertool(s|s)tatic`, not `(fingertools)|(static)`, and that's not going to work. Unless apache have non-greed regexes, but I never heard about that.

Comment: @J0HN The regex `|` operator works like `(fingertools)|(static)`, not `fingertool(s|s)tatic`.  This does not just apply to Apache.  "Greedy" means something completely different.

Comment: @BrunoFinger If it works to your satisfaction, I'd greatly appreciate you marking it as the answer by checking that green outline of a checkmark to the left of the answer.  Thanks!